# обработчик события onSaved в виджете TextFormField не работает

Tags: flutter, dart

Обработчик события **onSaved** в виджете **TextFormField** не работает.

```
onSaved: (String value) {
 setState(() {
  _strNameUser = value;
 });
},
```

Если я правильно понимаю, **String value** это текстовое значение, которе появляется в поле ввода. Затем, я могу его присвоить какой либо переменной. Но ничего не происходит. В контроллер все происходит. **Первый код** без контроллера, он не работает. **Второй код** с контроллером, который заменяет **onSaved**. Там код работает. В чем причина, чего я не понимаю?

**Первый код** без контроллера, он не работает.

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:string_validator/string_validator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 //объявление переменных
 String _strNameUser;
 String _strEmail;
 String _str;
 bool _a, _b, _c;

 //вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _strNameUser = '';
  _strEmail = '';
  _str = '';
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   _a = _strNameUser.isNotEmpty;
   _b = _strEmail.isNotEmpty;
   _c = isEmail(_strEmail);

   if(_a && _b && _c) {
    _str = 'user name : $_strNameUser\n email: $_strEmail';
   } else {
    _str = '';
   }
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.65),
     child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
       Container(
        height: 50.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextFormField(
         onSaved: (String value) {
          setState(() {
           _strNameUser = value;
          });
         },
         cursorColor: Color(0xffF56323),
         style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          fontSize: 22.0,
         ),
         decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'User Name',
          prefixIcon: (_a == null || _a) ? Icon(Icons.person, color: Color(0xffF56323)) : Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.pink),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
           borderSide: BorderSide(),
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ),
       Container(
        height: 50.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: TextFormField(
         onSaved: (String value) {
          setState(() {
           _strEmail = value;
          });
         },
         keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
         cursorColor: Color(0xffF56323),
         style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          fontSize: 22.0,
         ),
         decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Email',
          prefixIcon: (_b == null || (_b && _c)) ? Icon(Icons.email, color: Color(0xffF56323)) : Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.pink),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
           borderSide: BorderSide()
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ),
       Container(
        height: 50.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
         width: double.infinity,
         height: 50.0,
         child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
           _f1();
          },
          color: Color(0xffF56323).withOpacity(0.9),
          splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          child: Text(
           'Ok',
           style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 22.0,
           ),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ),
      ],
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.85),
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.pink,
       fontSize: 26.0,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

**Второй код** с контроллером работает.

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:string_validator/string_validator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 //объявление переменных
 TextEditingController _controllerUserName;
 TextEditingController _controllerEmail;
 String _strNameUser;
 String _strEmail;
 String _str;
 bool _a, _b, _c;

 //вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controllerUserName = TextEditingController();
  _controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  _strNameUser = '';
  _strEmail = '';
  _str = '';
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {
   _strNameUser = _controllerUserName.text;
   _strEmail = _controllerEmail.text;

   _a = _strNameUser.isNotEmpty;
   _b = _strEmail.isNotEmpty;
   _c = isEmail(_strEmail);

   if(_a && _b && _c) {
    _str = 'user name : $_strNameUser\n email: $_strEmail';
   } else {
    _str = '';
   }
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.65),
      child: Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
       children: <Widget>[
        Container(
         height: 50.0,
         margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: TextFormField(
          controller: _controllerUserName,
          cursorColor: Color(0xffF56323),
          style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.deepPurple,
           fontSize: 22.0,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'User Name',
           prefixIcon: (_a == null || _a) ? Icon(Icons.person, color: Color(0xffF56323)) : Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.pink),
           border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide(),
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        Container(
         height: 50.0,
         margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: TextFormField(
          controller: _controllerEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          cursorColor: Color(0xffF56323),
          style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.deepPurple,
           fontSize: 22.0,
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Email',
           prefixIcon: (_b == null || (_b && _c)) ? Icon(Icons.email, color: Color(0xffF56323)) : Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.pink),
           border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            borderSide: BorderSide()
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        Container(
         height: 50.0,
         margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50.0,
          child: FlatButton(
           onPressed: () {
            _f1();
           },
           color: Color(0xffF56323).withOpacity(0.9),
           splashColor: Colors.amberAccent,
           child: Text(
            'Ok',
            style: TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white,
             fontSize: 22.0,
            ),
           ),
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
           ),
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ],
      ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.85),
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.pink,
       fontSize: 26.0,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению вы не правильно поняли на счет метода onSaved, он нужен для того чтобы вызывать дополнительный код при сохранении, а value это для отправки в дополнительный код.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html

```
onSaved: (String value) {
  // This optional block of code can be used to run
  // code when the user saves the form.
},
```

Вам нужно вызывать сохранение формы:

```
Form.of(primaryFocus.context).save();
```

А на счет контроллера, вы правильно поняли, он как и следует из названия, управляет/контролирует что-то (в данном примере `TextFormField`)

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо! Я думал, он заменяет контроллер, оказалось нет. Работает только в связке Form.of(primaryFocus.context).save(); Разобрался. Может подскажите, как в AndroidStudio настроить space вместо tab не 2, а 1. Стандартным способом сделал. Но, когда нажимаешь на желтую лампочку и оборочиваешь код, то он опять превращается в пробел из 2 символов. Спасибо.

Comment: @Anton лучше привыкнуть к форматированию кода, так как это code style) Посмотрите на сайте flutter как настраивать analysis, вроде там есть данная настройка.